# Regular Expression for two cases

Tags: regex, regex-greedy, csv

I have the following sample strings that represent the various possibilities for things I want to find (3 variations, two samples of each)...

```
/testfolder1/property//catfud.json
/testfolder1/property/246810/newspaper.json
/testfolder1/property/98765454/rentalfile/1234567.json

/testfolder1/property//for-sale-adverts.json
/testfolder1/property/10006959/adverts.json
/testfolder1/property/10010951/single-ad/15892269.json
```

Is it possible to have a regex that matches the following from the above sample inputs?

```
catfud.json
newspaper.json
rentalfile

for-sale-adverts.json
adverts.json
single-ad
```

The criteria are to match the last token (delimited by `/`), excluding numeric tokens.

I have made several attempts at the regex, but they are all a mess and not worthy to be posted here.

Comment: Where's the code/regex pattern you've tried?

Comment: The conditions for the substring sought may be obvious to you, but please do elaborate on what exactly it is that you want to match. Is it the 4th token in a list separated by `/`? Does it have to start with `/testfolder1`? What is it?

Comment: Thanks guys... my previous efforts were in a mess by this stage.... but good call, I should have provided.  That said, Bohemian's answer nailed it and my efforts were way off.  Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
(?<=\/)(?!.*\/\D)\D[^\/]+
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/w35Q0aIz4T).

This regex ignores tokens that start with a digit.

Comment: Thanks Bohemian... perfect!